# SharePoint list item into PDF

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, html, flow, power-automate

I have a list in SharePoint - the result I need is any individual list item selected I need to output into a formatted PDF.

I have the power automate flow working ok with some template HTML code, but not sure how to complete the code, so it brings through the data from the selected list item.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [For a selected item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#for-a-selected-item) trigger using SharePoint connector in Power Automate.

This trigger allows you to start a flow for a selected item in a SharePoint list or library. You can use the columns of the list or library as output parameters (dynamic content) in your existing HTML template.

**References**:

1. [Run Power Automate flow from SharePoint - For a Selected Item trigger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Hp9CTd8zQU)
2. [Power Automate for a selected item SharePoint trigger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8MSGwXazZRM)

Comment: Ok thank you - so I have my flow in place which is working and it is creating a HTML table template, but not bringing through the variable data (list item).

Comment: It's simple, wherever you have static data in HTML template, replace it with SharePoint item data using **dynamic content**. Check this [article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-create-and-format-html-table-using-microsoft-flow-and-sharepoint-online/) or [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=37g5rkLlkmE) if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you could also launch a powerapp. the new powerapps print function can generate a do.

Answer (score 0):

There a few ways to do this, if you are only producing a few PDFs per month then have a look at the Encodian PDF controls (https://blog.encodian.com/2020/01/convert-sharepoint-list-items-to-pdf/) they work really well.  The free version allows you a set number of PDFs a month or you can purchase it for more.  I don't have anything to do with the company but their product has helped me out to do stuff that Flow can't do out of the box.

You can use place holders within the HTML text, then use the REPLACE function in Flow to replace the place holder with the list item content.  The downside is that the Flow can get a bit complicated if you are doing lots of replacements.

Answer (score 0):

I realize it's been some time since this post was originally created, but I wanted to contribute a solution here as well. It can help people looking to convert **SharePoint list items to PDF files**. It's worth mentioning upfront that this solution is a paid service with a free trial available. It significantly simplifies the process, requiring only a few easy steps in **Power Automate**.

To begin, you'll need to register for an account at **Plumsail** - [www.plumsail.com/documents](http://www.plumsail.com/documents) - for their **Documents** product. This product has a 30-day free trial. Once registered, you can create a process either by using one of their templates or by uploading your own. Detailed instructions on creating a process can be found in [this quick guide](https://plumsail.com/docs/documents/v1.x/user-guide/processes/examples/xlsx-employee-info-process-part.html).

Below I've provided outline of the **Power Automate flow** using Plumsail Documents action, and the picture of full flow. [And there's a full article as well as a YouTube video](https://plumsail.com/blog/convert-sharepoint-list-items-to-pdf/) that goes into all the details on how to set up a process and construct a Power Automate flow for converting SharePoint list items into PDF documents. This template is in Excel format, but when creating the process you'll be able to switch the output file format to PDF.

Power Automate flow:

1. To begin, click **My flows** > **+ New flow** > **Instant cloud flow**.
2. Next, select “**Manually trigger a flow**” trigger.
3. Next, add the **SharePoint "Get items"** action to your workflow. Select your SharePoint site and specify the list from which you want to export data.
4. Finally, locate the **Plumsail Documents** action named **"Start document generation process with JSON."** If this is your first time connecting Plumsail Documents in Power Automate, you'll be prompted to enter an **API key**. You can easily [generate an API key](https://plumsail.com/docs/documents/v1.x/user-guide/api-keys.html) in your Plumsail account and then copy and paste it back into Power Automate. Next, [select the process you've created](https://plumsail.com/docs/documents/v1.x/user-guide/processes/examples/xlsx-employee-info-process-part.html) in your Plumsail account. In our case, it's the "Purchase order" process, created from a free [Purchase Order template](https://plumsail.com/documents/templates/purchase-order/) available on the site. This process represents the template document that will be populated with data from the SharePoint list. In the "Template data" field, enter the code in JSON format. This code will establish connections between SharePoint list fields and tokens in the PDF document template.

This concludes the flow. If you have any other questions, feel free to ask[image]